opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp:72: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= i && i < (int)vv.size() in function 'getMat_'
Can you help me with this bug?
a and b are 2-double array and are defined with rows and cols.  a is a given matrix:
cv::resize(a,b,cv::Size(newrows,newcols),0,0,INTER_CUBIC);
I can compile, but got error in running below:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  OpenCV(4.10.0-dev) /home/xx/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp:72: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 0 \<= i && i \< (int)vv.size() in function 'getMat\_'

The code is below:
std::vector <vector<double>> at,ax;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    vector<double> v11;
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
            v11.push_back(double(4*i+j));           
        }
        at.push_back(v11);
    }
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    vector<double> v12;
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++) {
            v12.push_back(0);           
        }
        ax.push_back(v12);
    }       
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {      
        cout<<"  "<<at[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
cv::resize(at,ax,cv::Size(2,2),0,0,INTER_CUBIC);
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++) {      
        cout<<"  "<<ax[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

The results are:
  0  1  2  3
  4  5  6  7
  8  9  10  11
  12  13  14  15
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.10.0-dev) /home/taduong/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp:72: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 0 <= i && i < (int)vv.size() in function 'getMat_'

Aborted


In order to use cv::resize, you need cv::Mat (or class with compatible layout) as your matrices, not a std::vector <vector<double>>.

@wohlstad IDK, but looking at the documentation OpenCV seems to use proxy classes for the input and output to cv::resize. Those proxy classes take std::vector<std::vector<T>> as a constructor argument.

@john I was not aware of that option. Tried it now. I managed to reproduce the OP's result, so I suspect it is broken.

A side note: usnig a vector<vector<>> is not recommended for a 2D matrix (due to incontiguous memory layout). Better to have a 1D array with contiguous memory and manage the indices "manually". AFAIK that is what opencv actually uses with cv::Mat.

you have a 4x4 area and are trying to using cubic-interpolation (4x4 kernel) to get a 2x2 output - that does not seem possible. Also for downscaling cubic is not a good choice as it offers no quality benefit but has worse performance.

just use cv::Mat. don't fight the library. and if you're interested in image processing/computer vision, maybe go with Python instead. a lot more convenient all around.


Can you help me with this bug?

The source of your problem seems to be a bug in opencv library itself.
I am not sure if/when it will be fixed.
But anyway I would recommend using opencv (and cv::resize) with cv::Mat which is the natual matrix container for opencv.
It is also better suited to represent a 2D array than vector<vector<T>> thanks to contiguous memory layout which is more efficient and cache-friendly.
It is considered quite a good matrix class in general.
Here's an example how to use it in your case:
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    // Create and fill input:
    cv::Mat at1(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            at1.at<double>(j, i) = 4. * i + j;
        }
    }

    // Print input:
    std::cout << "Input:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            std::cout << "  " << at1.at<double>(j, i);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // Perform resize and create output:
    cv::Mat ax1;  // no need to initialize - will be done by cv::resize
    cv::resize(at1, ax1, cv::Size(2, 2), 0, 0, cv::INTER_CUBIC);

    // Print output:
    std::cout << "\nOutput:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            std::cout << "  " << ax1.at<double>(j,i);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

Output:
Input:
  0  1  2  3
  4  5  6  7
  8  9  10  11
  12  13  14  15

Output:
  2.03125  4.21875
  10.7812  12.9688

Side notes:

As commented above the cubic interpolation filter you chose is not a good one for these matrix sizes, but I assume in the real case they are bigger.
For more efficient access to cv::Mat elements, use cv::Mat::ptr to get a line pointer instead of accessing each element with cv::Mat::at.
Note that the indices to cv::Mat::at are given as (y,x) (i.e.  row,column) and not (x,y) as some might expect.


NB: cv::Mat really needs a method to pretty-print its contents, like numpy arrays, that is either C++/Python source, or comes with a method to read that back in, that isn't XML (cv::FileStorage)

@ChristophRackwitz I agree it would be helpful indeed.

Thank you all.  I have other approach to solve it, but I chose due to my computational strategy.  The example which is used in this case allows me to verify in MATLAB and was discussed in other case.  Again, thanks for your attempting to help me out.

@user28186790 happy to help. Please see this: What should I do when someone answers my question?.
